# How to make not required the email in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

When a costumer go and make an order, in my eshop, when he goes and put his personals infos, it ask to him to insert the Name, the Lastname and the Email where are required fields.
My question is, how can i make the email field make it not required?
The Prestashop version is 1.7
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible, the email is necessary for a uniqueness of your base, and allow each customer to have a secure single account, which he can then connect.

Regards

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not the answer you were after, then we can make a script that creates a random email address on the fly to prevent people from entering one, but they will not be able to log in later. If not, I'll let you close the question.

Comment: i'm sorry if you thought that i waited a specific answer. With your answer you helped me to understand why i could not find an answer to solve this problem and i appreciate for your further explanation. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I have done it,

[image]

There are some modules quick checkout or WhatsApp order that make mail not required and it makes an auto generated mail like 213125247634@shopurl.com

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).